# AutoMapper - how to choose not to perform "inner" maps?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I have a weird case and I'm pretty new to AutoMapper and I can't understand what's happening.

I have two classes

```
public class Person
{
    public List<Friend> Friends {get;set;}
}

public class PersonView : Person
{
    public new List<FriendView> Friends {get;set;}
}
```

and the map

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>().ForMember(d => d.Friends,
    o => o.ResolveUsing<FriendViewResolver>().FromMember(s => s.Friends));
```

but, I also have this map, which has its own mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Friend, FriendView>().ForMember(/* a lot of stuff */);
```

Now, Inside FriendViewResolver - I'm calling `Mapper.Map<Friend, FriendView>()` for each of the friends. But for some reason after it runs, some of the properties get lost and from stepping over the code, it seems AutoMapper does a second pass on the list.

I want to have the `FriendViewResolver` run on the list, because it is doing recursive stuff with the entire collection of `Friends`, but I don't understand why AM does a second pass if there's a resolver rule for the member.

I really hope it makes sense.

EDIT: the problem happens when I run `Mapper.Map<Person, PersonView>();`, I see it runs `FriendViewResolver` and has correct result, but next step in the debugger runs the maps again and messes up the already mapped objects.

Answer (score 4):

PersonView derives from Person. That's not how AutoMapper is supposed to be used. It should be used to map between different classes. What seems that you are trying to do here is that you have a domain model Person and you are trying to create a view model PersonView that will be used in the views. That's fine and exactly what you should do except that a view model should not derive from a domain model. It is independent. Then you use AutoMapper to map between them.

So your PersonView class should look like this:

```
public class PersonView
{
    public List<FriendView> Friends {get;set;}
}
```

and now you will have 2 mapping definitions:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Friend, FriendView>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>();
```

and when you have an instance of your domain model (Person) you will be able to map to a view model (PersonView).

Comment: this method actually works very well, I've used it everywhere with derived classes. I either transform or add data, why waste time specifying members again in the viewmodel if I can just inherit?

But my problem is - I don't want the list member to be transformed by AM - I want to do it myself with my own resolver.

Comment: Why inherit? One of the nice things of AutoMapper and separate view models is that the view model becomes designed for the view. Inheritance re-inforces a link between persistence model and views.

Comment: @JimmyBogard, do you think that the inheritance is the problem with what I'm trying to do? It seems to me that AM shouldn't try to map entities in a list member if it has a resolver

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get by with this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Friend, FriendView>().ForMember(/* a lot of stuff */);
```

The `<Person, PersonView>` map should automatically attempt to map the Friends properties, since they have the same name. The `<Friend, FriendView>` map should take care of the actual property mapping.

Comment: No, I mentioned why I need `FriendViewResolver` - it needs to run on the entire list, I cannot do 1-to-1 mapping

Comment: If that's the case, do you need the `<Friend, FriendView>` mapping declared? If you removed it (temporarily, for testing) does the `<Person, PersonView>` mapping work as expected?

Comment: I need to create that mapping, I'm calling it manually inside `FriendViewResolver`. Without it the `FriendViewResolver` can't retain the result (because input type is different), so there's a different problem then